# How to explain/suggest epistemological incapability

Tags: conversations, religion

Using the idea from Plato’s “Allegory of the Cave” how do you suggest a problem is a result of someone’s incapability to view the idea the same way you do, when they currently haven’t observed the idea that viewpoints could diverge to this extent?

Ex: Following, “I don’t see the use of being moral, when in the world nothing matters.”, to a religion advocate.

Or that...

“Either way it doesn’t matter since you won’t likely see that person again”, following a concern about virtuous nature, argued to a theological viewpoint

---

Note none of this details any part of my ideals or being, this is just the only idea I could imagine that would help convey the idea. This was made as an inquiry to a long thought question, not an attack meant to disprove

---

This would be used in context to remedy the problem. This could be philosophic education, debate, etc
I wouldn’t expect this to be used in casual situations, unless there was a debate

Comment: Are you saying those sentences to those people because they are currently having a problem in the discussed topic right then? Or are you just having a casual debate with the person?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about "Interpersonal Skills" in the context of this site. This is more about *how to I express/teach/convey an academic concept more clearly?* Someone may suggest that teaching and sharing ideas is a form of interpersonal skill, but if this site continues to appeal to ***any*** issue that happens to involve two people, I'm afraid this site will have a hard time finding any sort of focus at all.

Comment: I'm thinking this may be a little too broad to be answered well in this format. "Too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book" In this case I'm sure a multitude of books could and have been written to answer this question. See: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Before the last edit it seemed like it could be interpersonal if the OP was getting into these discussions a lot. But if it's in the context of debates, then yeah it's not very *interpersonal* in the this site's sense

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't seem to be about "Interpersonal Skills" in the context of this site. This is more about how to I express/teach/convey an academic concept more clearly? Someone may suggest that teaching and sharing ideas is a form of interpersonal skill, but if this site continues to appeal to any issue that happens to involve two people, I'm afraid this site will have a hard time defining any sort of focus at all.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I think this question would do better if you explain who you are trying to persuade (their age, their relationship to you, their culture), the specific reason why you are trying to persuade them, and what you've tried doing so far (and why that hasn't worked).

Comment: @Hamlet agreed that OP needs to clarify a bit.  I'll mention in passing that if he straight-out tells someone that they are "epistemologically incapable" that someone will get .. "epissed off".  Whatever happens, tact is key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what "The Cave" has to do with this, but in general if people are very used to a specific system of thinking they will not grasp any idea that is far outside of that, but will probably reinterpret that within their familiar paradigm.

I've actually known some people who have morals, and religious people and I've had similar conversations, and eventually if you manage to maintain discussion without pissing them off you just arrive to an *"agree to disagree"* or a *"you'll understand when you're older"* or something along those lines.

The fact is there are things that are both **TRULY IMPORTANT TO SOMEONE'S IDENTITY AND SENSE OF LIFE'S PURPOSE** while at the same time being **COMPLETELY IMPOSSIBLE TO PROVE**. So they are not going to abandon them, but they'll never convince someone who doesn't happen to share those beliefs (i.e. you) so you'll just reach an impasse (in the best case scenario).

I wouldn't recommend going down this conversational path unless they try to convince you first, and you are using this as a defense. But if you absolutely need to have such conversation, you'll have to start with initial assumptions so that you make it real clear to the other person just how far out from theirs your position is. i.e.

> What *are* morals, are they something people come up with? Are they universal? If so, how can determine what they are? etc.